# TypeScript with setTimeout() / async / await getting tslib error

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I'm trying to create a function in my Node.js TypeScript code that can be used to insert a sleep into my unit tests (I'm using the latest versions of Node.js and TypeScript).

```
static timeout(milliseconds: number): Promise<any> {  
  return new Promise((resolve: any): any => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));  
}  

static async sleep(milliseconds: number): Promise<any> {
  await CommonHelper.timeout(milliseconds);
}
```

However, it is causing the following error at runtime:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'  
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)  
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)  
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)  
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)  
at Object.<anonymous> (/service/build/main/common/common-helper.js:3:17)
```

Even when I add `tslib` to my `package.json`, I still get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What compiler settings do you use ?

Comment: `tsconfig.json`:  
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },

Comment: After almost 5 years, no answer :|